# Need to drop established connections with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, firewall, iptables

For app testing purposes, I need to simulate a situation, when a stateful firewall drops an established TCP connection from client to server by timeout. I installed 3 guest VMs in Virtualbox:

1. Client, network1 ip: 10.0.2.110
2. Firewall, network1 ip: 10.0.2.5, network2 ip: 10.0.3.5
3. Server, network2 ip: 10.0.3.6

Client and Server are Fedora19 with iptables disabled
Firewall is Ubuntu 13.10 with the following settings:

## cat /etc/iptables.conf

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [201:13136]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [110:14472]
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "[netfilter] "
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
```

## sysctl net.netfilter

```
...
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 30
...
```

With this settings, conntrack|iptables should drop established TCP connections after 30 seconds of inactivity.
To run the test, I set up "server" on Server:

```
# ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --exec "/bin/cat"
```

and connect there with telnet on Client:

```
$ telnet 10.0.3.6 2000
Trying 10.0.3.6...
Connected to 10.0.3.6.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

In iptables log I get a normal TCP handshake:

```
Dec  2 12:24:23 ubuntu kernel: [ 5231.169804] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44926 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  2 12:24:23 ubuntu kernel: [ 5231.170489] [netfilter] IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=08:00:27:00:72:8c:08:00:27:74:b7:df:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.6 DST=10.0.2.110 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2000 DPT=47899 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Dec  2 12:24:23 ubuntu kernel: [ 5231.171315] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44927 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

While connection is established, I send several packets with telnet and with `# conntrack -L` command, I get:

```
tcp      6 24 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.2.110 dst=10.0.3.6 sport=47899 dport=2000 src=10.0.3.6 dst=10.0.2.110 sport=2000 dport=47899 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

And in iptables log I get:

```
Dec  2 12:24:38 ubuntu kernel: [ 5245.917564] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=55 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44928 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Dec  2 12:24:38 ubuntu kernel: [ 5245.917961] [netfilter] IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=08:00:27:00:72:8c:08:00:27:74:b7:df:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.6 DST=10.0.2.110 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=36952 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2000 DPT=47899 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Dec  2 12:24:38 ubuntu kernel: [ 5245.918326] [netfilter] IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=08:00:27:00:72:8c:08:00:27:74:b7:df:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.6 DST=10.0.2.110 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=36953 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2000 DPT=47899 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Dec  2 12:24:38 ubuntu kernel: [ 5245.918535] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44929 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

that's also OK.

Next, I wait for several minutes and check that `# conntrack -L` returns an empty table, than I send some more packets with telnet and expect that it freezes or says something like "connection closed", but, to my surprise, connection isn't actually closed and I get such messages in iptables log:

```
Dec  2 12:29:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 5558.925402] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=55 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44930 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Dec  2 12:29:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 5558.925927] [netfilter] IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=08:00:27:00:72:8c:08:00:27:74:b7:df:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.6 DST=10.0.2.110 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=36954 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2000 DPT=47899 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Dec  2 12:29:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 5558.926237] [netfilter] IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=08:00:27:b8:68:9f:08:00:27:4f:ee:15:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.110 DST=10.0.3.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=44931 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47899 DPT=2000 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

No TCP handshake, that could indicate that telnet silently reestablished connection , no difference from previous log, where connection was established according to conntrack.

**How can I really make iptables to close established connection after 30 seconds of inactivity?**

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer, but some explanation of the behaviour: It seems that ip_conntrack tries to allocate the same source port which the internal client has used again on the external interface if it is available. That means, even after a complete wipe of the conntrack table it will be "transparently" re-establish on the same port and TCP sees no interruption. And actually you could consider this as a feature.

To verify this behaviour you would need 2 clients with the same source port connecting to the outside world and then see conntrack again (hard to get simulated as OS assigns source port numbers freely). You should get 2 different port numbers then. Only in this case the TCP connection might recognize that something happened in the meantime (which will be connection closed in most cases)...

Answer (score 1):

try to insert into FORWARD -m state INVALID -j DROP
this will drops packets without established connection.